# Formatting and Sending Client Messages, use of xxxService classes

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, tcp

Need some advice on class design. I've just started to use xxxService classes, so not really sure when and how to use them.

A number of (identical) client applications connect to this program with socket TcpClient. Different type of messages needs to be sent from several different classes. Should I call a service class, with static methods, whenever I need to send some message (like code below suggests), or should I rather raise an event, and have some class registered to those events, that will format and send the messages. That would be a more lose coupling, so perhaps that's a better idea?

That would kind of hide that sequence of events from these classes, but on the other hand, it would be a centralized class where one can see easily all events that trigger a message send. Which feels like a benefit.

Would like to hear some advice on this. And if my last suggestion makes sense, what could such class be called, and would it be considered a ..Service class?  Just to give me a better understanding.

cheers!

Example: (code is a bit "rough")

```
Class UserConnection 
   tcpClient As TcpClient

   Public Sub SendMsg(msg as String)
      ' Sending by tcpClient
   End Sub
End Class

Class UserAccount 
   userData as UserData
   conn As UserConnection
   balance as Decimal 

   Public Sub UpdateAccount(newBalance as Decimal)
       ' perform some logic
       Dim history as new AccountHistory(me.Balance, ......, ....) 
       UserMessageFormatSendService(history)
   End Sub
End Class          

Class UserMessageFormatAndSendService()
   Public Shared SendAccountUpdate(user as UserAccount, accountHistory as AccountHistory)
      ' Some code formatting it into a string message
      Dim msg = .......

      user.Conn.SendMsg(msg)
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UserMessageFormatAndSendService** should implement your service interface
say, **IUserMessageService** - this way you could test it and/or replace functionality when needed

The class itself (UserMessageFormatAndSendService) is not "The Service", it is a proxy to the real service, so you could call it **UserMessageServiceAgent**.